# Win10 WSL - No Ubuntu bootstrap when typing bash

Tags: windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I use Win10 Home edition; No special probs with the PC whatsoever; Software usually work fine, yet when I activate either CMD or Powershell and type bash, there's no Ubuntu Bootstrap.

This is a new problem: Never happened to me before in WSL...

It basically started after I did an mv command of a file from Home to Win10 Desktop.

Milestone:

I now notice that uninstalling isn't working as well, and printing this error: 0x80080005 ... Running CMD as Admin doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me it was this problem:

About an hour before I mistakenly turned on "Legacy console mode".

To cancel, co to CMD/Powershell properties and uncheck:

`Use Legacy console (requires relaunch)` in the end.